# Device "multipathed" onto /dev/sdd which is in use by another drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

FIX?:
I took all the data off of the drive that was multipathed and deleted all the partitions on it, then recreated them. This seemed to get rid of the issue.

Just now I wanted to hook up a new external drive to my Ubuntu server (running version 22.04). This drive was assigned `/dev/sdd` as the device file.

Later on, checking on the web interface I have set up for my server. I noticed that another external drive was "multipathed" onto `/dev/sdd`. Please see the images below.

This is what appears in the web interface when I click on any partition on either the `/dev/sdc` or `/dev/sdd` drive thus for any partition on the new drive.

[image: This]

These two give me the same information even though they are different drives.

[image: These two give me the same information even though they are different drives]

Output from running `lshw -class disk -short` in which you can see, the green selection is the new drive. and the pink one is the multipathed device.

[image: Output from running lshw -class disk -short]

I am able to mount my partition when using the UUID of the partition. I can not specify `/dev/sdd1` to be mounted anywhere. Please see this image to see how I currently have the 2 drive mounts set up in `/etc/ftab`.

[image: this image]

The upper drive is the drive that I am already using. the bottom one is the one I am trying to connect.

My question is, how is this possible and is there a way to remove the external SSD from being on that `/dev/sdd` path?

Comment: As initially stated, your question has no information that would help us help you. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you for your response @waltinator I will update the question. My apologies.

Comment: The one time I mounted something in /mnt, it blew away all my other mounts in /mnt. I use /mnt/data, /mnt/backup and several others. You need unique mount points. Best to just post full fstab. And if external drives you may want extra mount options. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654952/consistent-auto-mount-of-external-hard-drive  nofail and either systemd-automount or autofs can be used. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab#Automount_with_systemd

Comment: Thank you for your response @olfred, all my mount points are unique. I currently have the already existing drive mounted at "/mnt/sds" and the new one would be on "/mnt/backup". I will look into the other mount options. Thank you again!